# Function constructor browser support

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is supported down to IE7 (MDN says "?").

It seems to be working in IE10 using IE7 mode, but I can't install a native IE7 version since I'm on windows 7.

To anyone whos intrested in the use case:

```
// expressionFromServer example: 'x.foo < 3 && x.bar != 5'

var filteredRows = 
    $.grep(availableActivityRows, new Function('x', 'return ' + 
                                                    expressionFromServer + ';'));
```

Comment: It is supported in all version of IE atleast from IE6, I think what they mean by ? is all versions here

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use it in every browser, but I wouldn't recommend it. Why do you need to use it?

Comment: @AaditMShah I would like to pass a pretty complex callback function to `array.filter()` / `$.grep` from the server.

Comment: @Arun P Johny At MDN the question mark indicates, that the status is unknown. But as MDN is a wiki, you may add such information.

Comment: Why do you have your data on the client and the filer logic on the server?

Comment: @jantimon Its for a specific case only where the server don't know the connection between foo and bar. 99% is handled on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft MSDN, Function object is supported in following document modes:

- Quirks
- Internet Explorer 6 standards
- Internet Explorer 7 standards
- Internet Explorer 8 standards
- Internet Explorer 9 standards
- Internet Explorer 10 standards
- Internet Explorer 11 standards

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/x844tc74(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The operation of the `new Function` constructor is specified in [ECMAScript First Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm) and is implemented by all browsers with any level of JS support.